# EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xe7ffdefe)

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am getting this error.

[image]

It should be because of this code (it should switch between front and back camera in my custom camera). I am able to take a picture and everything works fine except this code...

```
 @IBAction func switchCamera(sender: UIButton) {

    var session:AVCaptureSession!

    let currentCameraInput: AVCaptureInput = session.inputs[0] as! AVCaptureInput
    session.removeInput(currentCameraInput)


     do {

    let newCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    if(captureDevice!.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back){
        print("Setting new camera with Front")
        newCamera = self.cameraWithPosition(AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front)
    } else {
        print("Setting new camera with Back")
        newCamera = self.cameraWithPosition(AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back)
    }

    let error = NSError?()
    let newVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera)
     if (error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(newVideoInput) != nil) {
        session.addInput(newVideoInput)
    } else {
        print("Error creating capture device input")
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()

    captureDevice! = newCamera!

     } catch let error as NSError {
        // Handle any errors
        print(error)
    }


}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you've set a break point...

Comment: The catch let error  function?